# Serilog not writing to file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

Setting up Serilog for my .net core app, everything compiles and runs but not writing to the file. How can I pinpoint the problem?

I am only use Serilog package - but there seems to be a multitude of others, and I'd be happy to use another one.

In my startup.cs I have

```
using Serilog;

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .MinimumLevel.Debug()
         .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
         .CreateLogger();
}
```

in my appsettings.json I have

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "C:\\log\\Batching\\apptest.log"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

in my Program.cs I have

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

And finally I use this statement to test the writing:

```
Log.Information("write something to file");
```

It is not working. What can I try next?

Comment: You mentioned you only installed the Serilog package. Serilog is very flexible in where it can log to, but you must install a NuGet package for an appropriate [Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) to actually send your logs somewhere. Have you installed the Serilog.Sinks.File package?  If you have, and you're still not seeing the logs, have you tried [setting up the SelfLog that the documentation suggests for troubleshooting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)?

Comment: @mason yes I am the master of snarky comments lol. I also have Serilog.Sinks.File installed. But the code above is not using it - I have the using Serilog.Sinks.File; statement added but it's greyed out which means redundant. This actually seemed off to me as well. My other question: should I be using Serilog or serilog for .net core? I have that installed and included as well but also greyed out

Comment: Should you be using Serilog? That's an opinion based question. Most apps need some sort of logging. As for whether Serilog vs NLog, vs Log4Net vs Microsoft.Extensions.Logging vs any other logging system - that's on you to decide. We use Serilog at my company, doesn't mean you have to. Having a using statement for Serilog.Sinks.File at the top of your C# class isn't necessary if you're using appsettings.json to configure your logger.

Comment: @mason...here we go.  I am not asking whether I should be using it. I am asking how to use it. I have been told to add it at work. Why? No idea, because programmers love new stuff.

Comment: You explicitly said "Should I be using Serilog" in your previous question. So if that's not what you meant to ask, then why did you say that? Make sure you're clear in what you're saying. If you don't understand *why* you're doing, other than you've been told to, then perhaps you should go research the benefits that Serilog brings to the table.

Comment: @mason...i meant should I be usign Serilog package or Serilog for aspnetcore package? That's what I meant. There are literally gazillion packages for this. Honestly this is not user friendly at all. I now have to spend time debugging the logger? All the loggers i set up before worked right away.

Comment: If you spend all your time complaining about how difficult it is, that's not productive. It's just exhausting and I'm not going to be motivated to help you. So just stop doing that. As for your actual question: I don't know of a NuGet package called "Serilog for aspnetcore". You'll need to link to it to make sure we're on the same page as to what package you're talking about. Do you mean [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore)? If you're using ASP.NET Core, then yes it makes sense to use that package, which includes the Serilog package as a dependency.

Comment: @mason so i don't need both Serilog and Serilog.aspnetcore?

Comment: Like I said, Serilog.AspNetCore package already includes Serilog (and Serilog.Sinks.File) as a dependency, so there's no need to explicitly install the Serilog package if you have the Serilog.AspNetCore package. Go [look at the dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/6.0.1#dependencies-body-tab) for yourself. Don't just take my word for it. It won't hurt if you do install Serilog package as well (so long as it's within the range of versions supported by the Serilog.AspNetCore package), but it's not necessary to do so.

Comment: @mason, I tried your suggestion of debugging the serilog but this line won't even compile Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));. It says Debug is not known in this context. Any help debugging the debugger is appreciated!

Comment: Debug is just the [static class in the System.Diagnostics namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug). It's built into .NET. You are using Visual Studio, right? If you're trying to use a class from a namespace that you don't have imported, you can simply type Control `.` and it will give you an option to fully qualify the object or add a using statement. If you want it to write to the console, you could just replace the word "Debug" with console. It's flexible - you choose to have it write the self log wherever you want it to go.

Answer (score 3):

Just as mentioned in the [document](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#json-appsettingsjson-configuration):

To use the file sink with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`, for example with ASP.NET Core or .NET Core, use the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` package

And you could find introduction to different packages in this page:
https://github.com/serilog

I tried with the packages:

[image]

Set as below in program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
        {
            var config = context.Configuration;
            configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(config);                     
        });
```

It works well in my case:

[image]

**Update:**

I configured as below in appsettings.json:

[image]

I also tried with the absolute path of my desktop, it worked either

Comment: thanks! where do you specify the log file location?

Comment: also, do you have this Serilog.Sinks.File installed? I am confused - some people say I need and some say I don't. Before serilog I never knew writing to a file is so complicated!

Comment: @sarsnake If you want to log to a file using Serilog, then installing the appropriate sink (Serilog.Sinks.File) is the right thing to do. I don't know who would say you don't need that if you're using Serilog and wanting to log to a file - so either they're wrong, or you're misunderstanding them. So, feel free to share a link to whoever is saying that.

Comment: @mason this answer does not mention including sinks. I am yet to find a full detailed example that actually works to log into a file with .net core. Looks like i may have to give up on this as i am not able to make this work.

Comment: @sarsnake It's very simple. If you want to give up, that's fine. It's your app. If you want to get it working though, make sure you provide enough info to debug the problem. I mentioned in the comments on your question how to enable the self log. Did you try it? Did you see anything? I saw no response on that.

Comment: @mason. thanks -  where does the self logger write to? It says user defined. user defined where and how?

Comment: @sarsnake You'll have to *read the documentation* that I linked you to. The very first code example shows it writing to Debug.WriteLine. But you don't have to send the self log there if you don't want to - you could write to the console, write to a file, or basically anywhere else that takes a string. Where do you want to see the self log? Make your decision, then configure the self log to log there.

Comment: ok, thanks. Read the documentation for error logger debugger, so ridiculous but I guess that's where we are at

Comment: @mason. thanks - can you tell me then why I need similar code of creating loggers and using them in both startup.cs and program.cs..all the guides mention bits and piece of code and not telling where these pieces go.  In startup, I read from configuration and create logger then in program.cs in this answer (look above) i also read from configuration...am I putting this in both?

Comment: @sarsnake Prior to .NET 6, ASP.NET Core used both Program.cs and Startup.cs. The default templates in .NET 5 combine all of that into .NET 6 (though nothing is stopping you from creating a Startup.cs if you prefer that, or if you upgrade a .NET 5 app to .NET 6). It's an incredibly simple change, and it's really nothing to get hung up about. This isn't a Serilog specific thing.

Comment: Hi,@sarsnake,I updated my answer and I've shown all packages I referred in the picture